# php-cgi not always terminating and locking sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, arm, embedded-linux, busybox

So I am having this occasional issue that is detrimental to my system.  This is small embedded ARM system that is serving web pages using busybox's httpd.  The pages are written in PHP and there is a sqlite3 backend.

What happens is occasionally when accessing pages on the system the system will start hanging.  What i have found is that the culprit seems to be that sometimes php-cgi is not terminating.  Something happens and it gets stuck open and it causes the sqlite3 database it accessed to be locked causing every other process to fail out trying to access it and basically everything slows to a crawl trying and failing to access this database.  If you continue to browse pages they just build up and pretty soon you have something like this:

```
CPU: 34.2% usr 24.5% sys 41.0% nic  0.0% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.1% sirq
Load average: 10.99 3.36 1.31 23/131 2172
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
1229  1208 root     S     107m 21.3   0 39.8 Router -t /tmp/volatileTables.d
1224  1208 root     S    81852 15.9   0 14.4 Messenger -t /tmp/volatileTable
2103  2102 root     R N  16740  3.2   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2106  2105 root     R N  16264  3.1   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2109  2108 root     R N  15612  3.0   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2112  2111 root     R N  15092  2.9   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2115  2114 root     R N  14708  2.8   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2118  2117 root     R N  14296  2.7   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2121  2120 root     R N  14036  2.7   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2124  2123 root     R N  13908  2.7   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2127  2126 root     R N  13908  2.7   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2131  2130 root     R N  13908  2.7   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2135  2134 root     R N  13776  2.6   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2142  2141 root     R N  13776  2.6   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2145  2144 root     R N  13776  2.6   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2151  2150 root     R N  13776  2.6   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2160  2159 root     R N  13332  2.5   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2163  2162 root     R N  12936  2.5   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2166  2165 root     R N  12780  2.4   0  2.1 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
2154  2153 root     R N  13776  2.6   0  1.9 /usr/bin/php-cgi all_stream.php
~ #
```

We were once able to get the load average all the way up to 50!  Messenger and Router are applications trying to access the database being locked by all the php scripts.

Any clues for me as to how to proceed?  Should I be using some other method to run the php files?  Should I maybe try lighttpd instead of busybox's httpd?  Is there something in my php.ini script I need to change maybe?  Something bad i am doing in my php scripts themselves?

Any clue in the right direction would be helpful!

Comment: Probably it is helpful to supply Linux kernel version and filesystem in use.  You might try to move the FS to a 'tmpfs/ramfs' if possible for testing.  Your embedded system might be using a flash filesystem, eMMC, etc.  DB programming usually wants a higher performance FS and this is often not a goal for embedded systems.  You need to isolate what component is at fault.  Maybe `strace` with only file operations on some processes would be helpful.  It doesn't look I/O bound and memory looks ok...  You might run out of network buffers or some other finite resource.  You could try *oprofile*.

Comment: Kernel Version:
3.2.07-ti2013.12.01 #87 Fri Jan 16 14:07:24 EST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

The filesystem is UBI stored in NAND.  The database itself is stored in tmpfs in RAM.  I could try copying the whole thing to RAM and see if it helps.  My file system is also pretty much completely read-only.  Any writeable mounts like /tmp and /var are tmpfs and i have one writeable persistent mount which is home and is mounted to a different area in NAND.

I will try some of your other suggestions as well.  I just have no idea what I am looking for at the moment, but hopefully something gives me some clues